# Starting apache fails (could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80)

Tags: apache, port, kill, netstat

Update: Already fixed, it seems that one of VirtualHosts configurations files was wrong in sites-enabled.

I have Ubuntu 11.10

When I run the command to start apache2:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I get the following error message:

> Starting web server apache2
>   apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName (98)Address already in
>   use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening
>   sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs Action 'start'
>   failed.

I run this command in order to get the process that is using the port 80:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

Which returns this output:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1176/
```

To know which process is I run this command:

```
ps -wlp1176
```

That returns:

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
5 D    33  1176     1  0  80   0 -     0 exit   ?        00:00:00 apache2
```

But if I try to kill the process:

```
sudo kill -9 1176
```

It doesn't kill it, if I run again the netstat command still appears listening and apache start fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what is pid 1176?  (`ps -wlp1176`)

Comment: 5 D    33  1176     1  0  80   0 -     0 exit   ?        00:00:00 apache2

Comment: So, does that suggest anything to you offhand?  Hint:  compare to what you're trying to start.

Comment: It seems to me apache it's already running, but it doesn't serve pages, it doesn't stop and it doesn't start or restart.

Comment: I just had a similar situation. apache2 process with a pid 1345 was taking the port 80 but did not respond to anything. `kill 1345` killed that process and then I could start a new apache2 process.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Worked for me running this command:

```
fuser -k -n tcp 80
```

Comment: Worked for me too in Debian 4.0.4.

Comment: I got this error every time restarting instance. do you know how to solve it completely?

Comment: For people not having problem with the port bind and getting a vhost syntax error, the first you have to do is look for Listen values. Look at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress at ***Conflicting Listen directives section***

Comment: This answer needs an explanation of WHY it works to be truly useful.

Answer (score 18):

It may be skype or nginx using the port 80.

Try shutting down skype, or running: `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, and just want to confirm that running

```
    sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

helped me indicate that Hiawatha webserver was in the way of Apache2.

Removing Hiawatha fixed the issue (sudo dpkg --purge hiawatha). 
Ubuntu 12.04.2 server.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem

For me, apache was already running but it was running the wrong way.

Killing processes didnt work because a daemon kept reinstantiating it.

```
apachectl stop
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

use either

```
sudo killall httpd
```

or

```
sudo killall apache2
```

check if some one using the 80 port

```
sudo netstat -tulpn| grep :80
```

The restart

```
sudo service httpd start
```

then restart the server.It took me a whole day to understand the issue

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me…

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

This would return the following:

```
tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1047/apache2
```

Then

```
sudo kill -9 1047
```

Then I was able to restart Apache and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to device manager, select “show hidden devices” from menu/view, go to “Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP, double click it to disable it (and disable or manual some services depended on it).
Reboot and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This will happen because of repeated installation of apache or port is using by another service

```
sudo lsof -i | grep "httpd"
```

You will find process id and listening port of service. Then check

```
cd /proc/(process id of http)
```

Then kill that process using command

```
kill -9 pid
```

now

```
sudo netstat -nltp
```

again kill the process

syntax:-

```
kill -9 pid
```

and now start apache

```
sudo ./apachectl start
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like other process is using port 80.

```
$ netstat -anp | grep
```

eg. `$ netstat -anp | grep 80`

by above you get process name, if you want to use port then you need to stop the process or change the port

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is simply check if the following is set in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-domain-name.com.conf

```
SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile /your/path/to/your-domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /your/path/to/your-domain.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /your/path/to/your-domain.com.ca-bundle
```

and there aren't any mistyped directories or anything else that would not supposed to be in your .conf file. It did the trick for me as re-starting and killing the processes did not help at all. It did not start anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using below procedure.
Run below command as root user.

```
root# ps aux |grep apache
```

It will show you Apache PID, just kill that PIDs and restart Apache Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have listen PORTNUMBER in only one file of .conf. Do not put it in multiple files. Try it :)