# Unable to start Apache - Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I am unable to restart Apache.

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
Monitored apache

Google Cloud Compute Engine - Bitnami Wordpress Multisite

Comment: Did you updated something on a Virtual Host or the Apache config? Also, did you take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by typing in the command:

```
kill lsof -t -i:80
sudo killall apache2
```

Comment: the first command gives me an error, the second one solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have another application running in port 80. It is highly likely that, apart from the Bitnami Apache, you also have installed another Apache, for example using `apt-get install`. I advise you to check if that is the case and, if so, remove it or stop it.