# Failed to start the Apache HTTP Server - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, apache, forum, mybb

I am completely new to Ubuntu and everything and am just trying to set up MyBB on my VPS with OVH. When I restart my Apache server using sudo systemctl -l status apache2, I get an error that says:

> Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: Action 'start' failed.
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 apachectl[18213]: The Apache error log may have more information.
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Nov 02 09:48:19 vps607432 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

I understand what the issue is here as it plainly says inside of the error what is wrong. It's just that I am unsure on how I would go about solving this issue that I am experiencing.

Thanks for taking the time to read this question, I hope that I am able to find a solution as fast as possible.

Comment: Looks like port 80 is already used by some other process in your system. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080) may help you

Comment: I can see that, it's just that I don't know how I would fix this issue so that it is not in use by another process.

Comment: "_When I restart my Apache server using sudo systemctl -l status apache2_" `sudo systemctl -l status apache2` doesn't restart your Apache, it shows its status

Comment: Sorry, I meant sudo service apache2 restart . Anyway, I restarted the whole VPS and that seems to have worked but I am unsure of what state it has left the system in and whether it will be a long term or short term fix.

Comment: Next time it occurs (if ever) run `sudo lsof | grep LISTEN | grep http`.  This will show you which process is holding port 80.  Then kill it and figure out why it was blocking the port.