# Cant's start Apache2

Tags: apache

I reinstall Apache2 and if I type `sudo systemctl status apache2` it goes

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server


  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-09-30 10:31:41 KST; 1min 30s ago
 Main PID: -- (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 9월 30 10:31:41 -- systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: Action 'start' failed.
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- apachectl[30008]: The Apache error log may have more information.
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 9월 30 10:31:41 -- systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I already tried remove and reinstall by `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and `sudo apt-get install apache2` but it keep says failed...

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: "*Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80*" - something is already running on port 80.  If you search for that error you will find many answers here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting apache fails (could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried everything but something is wrong.  after sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80' i can see something is already on port 80 However, even if i kill this by sudo kill -9 number, it keeps comes up with new number...and also if i enter my ip adress i can go to the website that i set before i delete apache...do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: If you kill it and it restarts automatically, something is doing that. Eg maybe it is a Docker container configured to always restart, or maybe supervisord is managing it, or ...?  You'll have to find out what is doing it, and disable it.  Or uninstall it completely.

Comment: It worked after uninstall nextcloud which i installed by snap. Thank you so much for helping me you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I installed nextcloud by snap which is why i couldn't delete 80 port. After i tried `sudo snap remove nextcloud` i could restart apache2.